# finding functions $f, g$ so $g(f(x)) = x + 4$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

I'm trying to find an example for functions $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, so that $g(f(x)) = x + 4$,
where  $f$ is not surjective and $g$ is neither surjective nor   injective.

---

I thought about $f(x) = x + 1$ and $g(x) = x + 3$ but then $g$ is injective...

Comment: Try $f = x+3$, $g = 1$ if $x < 4$, $g=x+1$ if $x \ge 4$ (change the $4$ to $3$ if you include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x+4$ and  $g(x)=x $ for any $x\geq5$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x<5$.

Comment: So $g(f(x))$ never has the value 1?

Comment: If $g(f(x))=x+4$ it can't ever be $1$.( Else $x=-3$)